# option (maxrecursion 0) SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

where is a bad idea to use this.
Although there is a base case and an instruction that eventually terminates recursion.

```
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use it when you need to use it.

The important thing is that your recursion *will* terminate eventually...

For example, [this](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx) I found on the internet (creates a date table) specifies use we use MAXRECURSION

Comment: So you do not worry for any problem in memory....It depends on the machine where it is running, right?

Comment: You wouldn't normally worry about memory in any query. A CTE is just a set based way of recursion: memory wise, is it any different to running a query over a 500 million row table?